# При возврате к Activity сбрасываются значения listview

Tags: android, listview, activity

На гиф видна проблема: при возврате к предыдущему activity, сбрасывается список. Как можно решить проблему ?

[image]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/label_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".TeamActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".TeamActivity"
        android:label="@string/label_team"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

TeamActivity.java

```
Button continueBtn;
ListView listView;
TeamAdapter adapter;

ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("Team 1");
    add("Team 2");
}};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_team);

    continueBtn = findViewById(R.id.team_continues);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.team_lv);
    listView.setDivider(null);

    // Add button addBtn as last item of listView
    listView.addFooterView(((LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.team_btn_add, null, false));
    adapter = new TeamAdapter(this, values);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void addItem(View v) {
    values.add("Team " + (values.size() + 1));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setSelection(listView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
}

public void startSettingsActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

team.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".TeamActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/team_lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/team_continues"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/team_continues"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
    android:text="@string/continues"
    android:onClick="startSettingsActivity"
    android:textSize="32sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ArrayList<String> values надо сохранять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предложил сохранить данные в отдельные класс и при возврате в активность проверять наличие данных в стороннем классе. Такой класс называется синглтоном. Создаем класс-синглтон:

```
public class OurSingleton {

    private static OurSingleton instance;
    
    private OurSingleton (){}
    
    public static synchronized OurSingleton getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new OurSingleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    
}
```

добавляем переменную:

```
ArrayList<String> inValues = new ArrayList<String>()
```

после этого делаем вытаскивание и добавление данных в этот массив:

```
private OurSingleton () {
   inValues  = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public ArrayList<String> getArray() {
  return this.inValues;
}

public void addToArray(String value) {
  inValues.add(value);
}
```

дальше в активности где происходит добавление данных при первом запуске проверяем наличие данных в массиве:

```
if(OurSingleton.getInstance().getArray().size > 0){
   // если он не пустой то добавляем с него данные в ваш список
}else{
   // если он пустой то добавляем с него дефолтные данные и грузим в список
   OurSingleton.getInstance().getArray().add("any value");
}
```

Так же есть другой вариант - сохранять данные в активности и когда вы на нее будете возвращаться то их восстанавливать. Вот есть пример ниже:

```
ArrayList myArrayList;

//put value of myArrayList in some other method

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArrayList("myArrayList", myArrayList);
}


protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    myArrayList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("myArrayList");
}
```